# If I have a substantial explanation that clarifies a complex problem, where should I post?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a question which involved someone asking about a way to workaround a compiler error in their code (it involved type casting, and for semantic reasons they knew it would succeed at runtime, but the compiler was marking an error). They suggested that they thought a reflective solution might help, but couldn't envision it.

Thinking about the problem, I realized why reflection wouldn't work, and had some insight into the fundamental issue the compiler was bound to run into. I wanted to share this insight for the asker and for future viewers of the question. Normally I would post such a problem-clarification insight in a comment on the question. However, this explanation was lengthy enough not to fit in the comment space.

However, I thought that a problem clarification didn't really belong as an answer. Furthermore, someone had already suggested a workaround as an answer that involved some code restructuring to avoid the issue, but didn't explain what the problem had been in the first place. Since such an answer existed, I was really hesitant to post my insight as an answer.

So- my question: **If I have a substantial insight that clarifies a problem, but doesn't answer it and is too big for a comment, where do I put it?**

Comment: start a chat with the OP and explain it to them there?  They can then incorporate that information into the OP if they feel it is appropriate.  It might also make sense to ask a new question that whatever information you've come up with *does* answer, and then link to that.

Comment: Also, if your insight is that substantial, it might be that the question is too broad or not clear.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The problem was clear in that it was asking about a very specific compiler problem, but the poster didn't seem to understand why the compiler wouldn't ever in principle be able to accommodate their needs. Here's a link to the [question spawning this conumdrum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669752/dynamic-type-casting/30671415#30671415). You'll note my eventual solution was to tag a less elegant workaround onto my insight so it would fit as an answer, but I realize this is sloppy.